# Autofill firefox extension, NameField identifier to match

Tags: autofill

i have a problem. i have a lot of pages where i would like to auto fill data. example field to fill is:

`^costs\[13\]\[37\]\[BGN\]\[cod_cost\]$`

The problem is that there are different values *13* and *37* on each page. i would like the autocomplete to work on any values, not just these two.
I don't know how to do it.
Please help

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow, this question is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here, but it may fit on [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).